# Variable initialization on TF 2.x after updating from TF 1.x model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Im trying to update a TF 1.x model to Tensorflow 2.x, by running the given scripts to automatically update the code (tf_upgrade_v2), and the only problem I found was when initializing the graph variables.

The new model looks like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from utils import *

import tensorflow as tf

    class NNet():
    def __init__(self, args):
        # game params
        self.board_x = args.boardX
        self.board_y = args.boardY
        self.action_size = args.actionSize
        self.args = args

        # Renaming functions 
        Relu = tf.nn.relu
        Tanh = tf.nn.tanh
        BatchNormalization = tf.compat.v1.layers.batch_normalization
        Dropout = tf.compat.v1.layers.dropout
        Dense = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense

        # Neural Net
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        with self.graph.as_default(): 
            self.input_boards = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.board_x, self.board_y])    # s: batch_size x board_x x board_y
            self.dropout = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32)
            self.isTraining = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.bool, name="is_training")

            x_image = tf.reshape(self.input_boards, [-1, self.board_x, self.board_y, 1])                    # batch_size  x board_x x board_y x 1
            h_conv1 = Relu(BatchNormalization(self.conv2d(x_image, args.num_channels, 'same'), axis=3, training=self.isTraining))     # batch_size  x board_x x board_y x num_channels
            h_conv2 = Relu(BatchNormalization(self.conv2d(h_conv1, args.num_channels, 'same'), axis=3, training=self.isTraining))     # batch_size  x board_x x board_y x num_channels
            h_conv3 = Relu(BatchNormalization(self.conv2d(h_conv2, args.num_channels, 'valid'), axis=3, training=self.isTraining))    # batch_size  x (board_x-2) x (board_y-2) x num_channels
            h_conv4 = Relu(BatchNormalization(self.conv2d(h_conv3, args.num_channels, 'valid'), axis=3, training=self.isTraining))    # batch_size  x (board_x-4) x (board_y-4) x num_channels
            h_conv4_flat = tf.reshape(h_conv4, [-1, args.num_channels*(self.board_x-4)*(self.board_y-4)])
            s_fc1 = Dropout(Relu(BatchNormalization(Dense(h_conv4_flat, 1024, use_bias=False), axis=1, training=self.isTraining)), rate=self.dropout) # batch_size x 1024
            s_fc2 = Dropout(Relu(BatchNormalization(Dense(s_fc1, 512, use_bias=False), axis=1, training=self.isTraining)), rate=self.dropout)         # batch_size x 512
            self.pi = Dense(s_fc2, self.action_size)                                                        # batch_size x self.action_size
            self.prob = tf.nn.softmax(self.pi)
            self.v = Tanh(Dense(s_fc2, 1))                                                               # batch_size x 1

            self.calculate_loss()

    def conv2d(self, x, out_channels, padding):
      return tf.compat.v1.layers.conv2d(x, out_channels, kernel_size=[3,3], padding=padding, use_bias=False)

    def calculate_loss(self):
        self.target_pis = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.action_size])
        self.target_vs = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
        self.loss_pi =  tf.compat.v1.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(self.target_pis, self.pi)
        self.loss_v = tf.compat.v1.losses.mean_squared_error(self.target_vs, tf.reshape(self.v, shape=[-1,]))
        self.total_loss = self.loss_pi + self.loss_v
        update_ops = tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
        with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
            self.train_step = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(self.args.lr).minimize(self.total_loss)
```

With a wrapper:

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

sys.path.append('../../')
from utils import *

import tensorflow as tf
from rummiNet_v2 import NNet as net

    args = dotdict({
    'lr': 0.001,
    'dropout': 0.3,
    'epochs': 10,
    'batch_size': 64,
    'num_channels': 512,
    'boardX': 7,
    'boardY': 8,
    'actionSize': 97
})


class NNetWrapper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.nnet = net(args)
        self.board_x = args.boardX
        self.board_y = args.boardY
        self.action_size = args.actionSize

        self.sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=self.nnet.graph)
        self.saver = None
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as temp_sess:
            temp_sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
        #self.sess.run(tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer(self.nnet.graph.get_collection('variables')))
        #Not needed in tf2

def predict(self, board):
    """
    board: np array with board
    """
    # timing
    start = time.time()

    # preparing input
    board = board[np.newaxis, :, :]

    # run
    prob, v = self.sess.run([self.nnet.prob, self.nnet.v],
                            feed_dict={self.nnet.input_boards: board, self.nnet.dropout: 0,
                                       self.nnet.isTraining: False})

    # print('PREDICTION TIME TAKEN : {0:03f}'.format(time.time()-start))
    return prob[0], v[0]
```

As you can see on the constructor of the NNet, at the end I've commented

> self.sess.run(tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer(self.nnet.graph.get_collection('variables')))

Cause It was producing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/WD Black/Clases/PSI/alpha-zero-java/python/connector.py", line 127, in <module>
    c = Connector()
  File "/Volumes/WD Black/Clases/PSI/alpha-zero-java/python/connector.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.neuralNet = NNetWrapper()
  File "/Volumes/WD Black/Clases/PSI/alpha-zero-java/python/nnet_v2.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.sess.run(tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer(self.nnet.graph.get_collection('variables')))
  File "/Users/lexy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 970, in run
    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
  File "/Users/lexy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1178, in _run
    fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
  File "/Users/lexy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 488, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/Users/lexy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 265, in for_fetch
    raise TypeError(f'Argument `fetch` = {fetch} has invalid type '
TypeError: Argument `fetch` = None has invalid type "NoneType". Cannot be None
```

And as said [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/variables_initializer), "In TF2, variables are initialized immediately when they are created. There is no longer a need to run variable initializers before using them.".

But when I comment it, when forwarding the nnet, it gives the following error, suggesting that I there is not initialized variables.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lexy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1380, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Users/lexy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1363, in _run_fn
    return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
  File "/Users/lexy/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1456, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(self._session, options, feed_dict,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Could not find variable dense/kernel. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status error message=Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense/kernel)
         [[{{node dense/MatMul/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

There is more exceptions on the error stack trace, but as it suggest, probably they are produced by this one.

Im really lost with this one, thank you!

Some more dependencies to run the code:

```
class AverageMeter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.avg:.2e}'

    def update(self, val, n=1):
        self.val = val
        self.sum += val * n
        self.count += n
        self.avg = self.sum / self.count


class dotdict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]
```

Comment: How do you execute this ? Is this a game board ? I don't see that error when it is commented.

Comment: There is a little more code, this is run from from another class called connector, that runs a tcp socket connected to a java program. All this comes from a college project, and we have to develop an android app to play rummikub. As I found, the java TF library is not in maintenance, so the idea is to train the nnet on python, convert it to a TF lite model and insert it on java afterwards. The problem doesn't show up until I call the predict method. I think is easy to simulate, just call predict with board as a np array 7x8 with values [-1,0,1]. That should do the trick. Thank you for ur help!

Comment: Ive added the last needed class, called utils. Im recycling code from https://github.com/suragnair/alpha-zero-general

Comment: `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` works. You could check your results.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, It is working now, but, is there anything I have to take in account when using graph execution?